# Which version of SendGrid is compatible with AFNetworking 3.0?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, cocoapods, sendgrid, afnetworking-3

In my app, I'm sending emails through SendGrid (0.2.0). Sendgrid was working properly with afnetworking 2.0 but due to some reason, I had to update afnetworking version from 2.0 to 3.0. But now SendGrid is giving errors.So I update it too through a pod.

pod error - Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `AFNetworking (~> 3.0)` required by `Podfile`
- `AFNetworking (~> 2.0)` required by `SendGrid (0.3.0)`

content of Podfile:

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
target ‘Projectname’ do
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0’
pod 'SendGrid', '~>  0.3.0’
end

Can anybody tell me how to resolve this issue?

thank you!

Comment: Just update Pod version  of `SendGrid` with latest version , Like `pod 'SendGrid', '~>  0.3.0'`

Comment: @PiyushPatel, I have done the same way as you said. But pod error still persists.

Comment: Just update Pod version of SendGrid with latest version , Like pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'

Comment: @sarita Try with `pod 'AFNetworking'`
              `pod 'SendGrid'` without specifying version

Comment: @sarita You can't use AFNetworking's version `3.0` because `SendGrid (0.3.0)` is not compatible with that version  of `AFNetworking` so you have use `AFNetworking (2.6.3)`

Comment: If you still want to use `AFNetworking (3.0)` you have to customize `SendGrid`

Comment: thank you! @PiyushPatel for paying attention towards my question. Would you please brief me about the things I need to customise SendGrid.

Comment: @sarita Ok i will explain it in answer.

Answer (score 1):

To Customize `SendGrid` there are some point to pay attention.

- You have to add `sendGrid` manually without Pods.
- Add AFNetworking 3.0 using Pod.

Now, in `SendGrid`  there is one method :

```
- (void)sendWithWeb:(SendGridEmail *)email successBlock:(void(^)(id responseObject))successBlock failureBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error))failureBlock
```

That method you have to edit like as follow

```
- (void)sendWithWeb:(SendGridEmail *)email successBlock:(void(^)(id responseObject))successBlock failureBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error))failureBlock
{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                                              URLString:self.baseURL
                                                                                             parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

                                                                                                 for (int i = 0; i < email.imgs.count; i++)
                                                                                                 {
                                                                                                     UIImage *img = [email.imgs objectAtIndex:i];
                                                                                                     NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];
                                                                                                     NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"files[image%d.png]", i];
                                                                                                     NSLog(@"name: %@, Filename: %@", name, filename);
                                                                                                     NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
                                                                                                     [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:name fileName:filename mimeType:@"image/png"];
                                                                                                 }


    }
                                                                                                  error:nil];

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
    uploadTask = [manager
                  uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
                  progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                      // This is not called back on the main queue.
                      // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                          //Update the progress view
                      });
                  }
                  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                      if (error) {
                          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                          failureBlock(error);
                      } else {
                          NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
                          successBlock(responseObject);
                      }
                  }];

    [uploadTask resume];
}
```

Like this you have to edit methods.
Do editional changes as per your requirement.

**Note**

That's not tested code. its just example.